# System Crashes, SSD Boot Partition Not Found after Power Surge

Tags: partition, startup, ssd

Hi all—I've read this community for a long time, and am now hoping you can help me more directly.

I was using my 2012 MacBook Pro last night when the power in my home went out and came back. The laptop was connected to the charger, no surge protector (I know, I know—never again.)

The system pinwheeled indefinitely, and when I restarted, I got the folder icon with "?", indicating no boot volume found.

However, when I put the SSD in a USB caddy and connected it to another computer, the "Macintosh HD" and "BOOTCAMP" partitions appeared. This was really lucky, as I was able to copy my important files to another disk. I was also able to successfully "Repair" the disk, APFS container, and "Macintosh HD" volume using Disk Utility.

I then put the SSD back in the MacBook, and it booted normally. However, after a few minutes of use, the pinwheel came back, just like it did during the surge, and the system became unresponsive. When I restarted, the boot partition was once again not found. I've repeated this cycle 2-3x at this point.

Additionally, I have found that I am able to boot the MacBook from the SSD in the USB caddy. That is how I am writing this post, and the system is far more stable this way (it has been up now for 25 minutes—very responsive, no pinwheel.)

So what could this be—and what are my options, from minimal to nuclear? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your SSD seems to be ok, so potentially the SATA port has a problem. You might try swapping out the optical drive and replacing it with an SSD caddy - so that you can try using the other SATA port. Alternatively I'd be tempted to try a new SSD, just to confirm there isn't some issue with the original SSD:

Comment: You had a power event so I'd start with a reset of the SMC (it manages power).  I can't see how a power surge would go through your power adapter all the way down to the SATA controller and not affect anything else especially since your adapter is *optically isolated* between the mains and DC side of the adapter.  The next thing I would check is your DC in board.  If that's not faulty - I'd recommend getting a new Mac because the cost/benefit to fix the logic board simply isn't there.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I replaced the drive cable and that seems to have done it; I currently have uptime of over 5 days, and the computer wakes from sleep without issue. It is weird to me that the surge would only take out the data cable, but I'm glad it was a cheap and easy fix. Still, I will be careful and backup regularly in case other issues come to light in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I was able to restore my computer to normal operation by replacing the drive cable (see my comment above. ) I was very lucky.